# Angular and Laravel - fetch data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I need to fetch data from my database, updated a div and onclick update another div.
I managed to fetch the data but I fail to load additional by onCLick.

My Code:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.fetcheddata = [];
$scope.loading = false;

$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('/api/content').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.fetcheddata = data;
            $scope.loading = false;

    });
}
$scope.getDesc = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('/api/content/get/' + item.id).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.fetcheddata = data;
            $scope.loading = false;

    });
}

$scope.init();
```

});

View Code:

```
 <div class="col-xs-2 type-image" tr ng-repeat='item in fetcheddata'>
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail click-productgroup" data-group="show-<% item.group %>">
       <img src="<% item.image %>" class="img-responsive">
     </a>
  </div>
```

The -tag should fetch the item.description and update another div. How can I do that?
I tried with an getDesc scope. Is this right? But how do I updated the div?

EDIT 1:

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7" id="productGroups">
                        <div class="row type-row">

                            <div class="col-xs-2 type-image" ng-repeat='item in fetchedData'>
                                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" ng-click='getDesc(<% item.id %>)'>
                                    <img src="<% item.image %>" class="img-responsive">
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 type-description">
                    <% fetchedDesc | json %>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.getDesc = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('/api/content/get/' + item.id).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.fetchedDesc = data.description;
            $scope.loading = false;

    });
}
```

Still the page jumps on click to the top and no content in the div (although ng-binding appears in the html).

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to fetch it!

Comment: you just have to place `{{ item.description }}` where you want to show it isnt it?

Comment: use, but I those are several items which are loaded in the ng-repeat. I need one description on click for a chosen item after the load.

Comment: Oh I see you want to show description on click of anchor tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the page is jumping because the href of your anchor tag is `#`, remove that to stop it from happening :).

Secondly, I think the best way of achieving what you're after would be to ensure that each item fetched from the server in the `$http.get('/api/content')` call has the description as a property, rather than fetching it seperately, and then do something like this:

```
$http.get('/api/content').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });


$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

And in the view:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 type-image" tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail click-productgroup" ng-click="selectItem(item)">
        <img src="{{ item.image }}" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    {{ selectedItem.description }}
</div>
```

Comment: this is it... I also accidentally added the <% tags to selectItem() - now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I notice that is your `getDesc` you don't pass `item.id`?

```
$scope.getDesc = function(item) {
 $http.get('/api/content/get/' + item.id)
   .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
   })
}
```

This should come from `ng-click` of the `div` tag?

```
 <div class="col-xs-2 type-image" tr ng-repeat='item in fetcheddata'>
     <a href="#" class="thumbnail click-productgroup" data-group="show-<% item.group %>" ng-click="getDesc(item)">
       <img src="<% item.image %>" class="img-responsive">
     </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I did that know. Still the page jumps and I the description div has ng-binding but now content.